# insert into select on duplicate key update values(...) with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have read that the function "values ()" is being removed in a future version - and I am therefore looking for an alternative - to if you have an "insert into select" command.
I have searched a lot on the web, but do not think I have found an answer - when it comes to "select" ...
Let's say I have 2 tables (t1 and t2) and some summations need to be written in t1 from t2.

t1:

| product_id | quantity | total_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 80 |

t2:

| product_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 40 |
| 2 | 50 |

Normally I would do it as follows:

```
insert into t1 (product_id,quantity,total_value) 
select product_id,count(*),sum(value) 
from t2 group by product_id on duplicate key update quantity=values(quantity),total_value=values(total_value)
```

This will give the following result:

t1:

| product_id | quantity | total_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 150 |
| 2 | 2 | 90 |

But how do I do something similar if I can not use "values ()" ..?
It is of course an option to delete the relevant rows in t1 first - to avoid having a "duplicate key" at all - but is there no better way ..?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that you cannot use `values()`?

Comment: "values()" is deprecated in MySQL 8.0 according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html

Answer (score 0):

> Normally I would do it as follows:

Use SELECT aliases:

```sql
insert into t1 (product_id, quantity, total_value) 
select * 
FROM ( SELECT product_id AS p, count(*) AS q, sum(value) AS s
       from t2 
       group by p ) src
on duplicate key update quantity=q, total_value=s
```

> But how do I do something similar if I can not use "values ()" ..?

The same

```sql
insert into t1 (product_id, quantity, total_value) 
VALUES (1, 10, 100) AS x(p, q, s)
on duplicate key update quantity=q, total_value=s
```

<kbd>**[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58a7e7491093b64e91917f6489b369e4)**</kbd>

Comment: I have now tried the first command with insert into select - and it gives me an error...:
"Unknown column 'q' in 'field list'"

Comment: @dannielsen Code corrected, fiddle added.